# My dlink power supply broke, I found a similar one on old boxes. Is it going to damage my router if used (specs and pic inside)?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have an old dlink wi-fi router to connect old 802.11g devices at home. It's power supply just fried after a storm.

Buying a new power supply is almost the same price as a used router like mine, and I found a power supply at home from an older router (not even wi-fi) I was planning to use it, but I don't have that much experience with eletronics... Can someone tell me if they are compatible?

### FRIED POWER SUPPLY

[image: Fried power supply specs]

---

### ALTERNATIVE POWER SUPPLY

[image: Alternative power supply specs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Alternative Power supply would be compatible.

It has a higher current limit than the old one -- which is good.

There's no indication of the polarity of the output for the old supply, but the alternative one (with the +ve connection in the centre) looks like the standard, so I think you're OK.

But beware that if the old power supply was fried in a storm, *some* of the surge *may* have appeared on its output and the router may have been damaged too.

You'll have to take a chance and try it.

Comment: I've tested the router with fried power supply elsewhere, it's working. The only problem is with the power supply.

Comment: That's good news. I once had a lightning strike at home, and it *killed* all the equipment.

Comment: I tested and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the connector fits and the polarity is correct (center positive in the case of the new supply), you should be able to use it.

The most important thing are the voltages, which match. The second most important thing is the current (amps), which is actually greater. The current correlates to the ability to do work. If it were less, it would not be able to deliver the necessary voltage (without problems i.e. ac leaking into the dc), which would cause problems in the router, but since it is greater, that is not a problem.

It is advisable to look on the router to see if it needs center positive or center negative.

Comment: Some Linksys router power adapters are not DC output, but AC, so any adapter may not work if it is not the proper AC or DC output, and will damage the router, just a warning. The connector size is irrelevant. You notice that label does not specify the output if it is AC or DC.

Comment: The top one does not, but it is still almost certainly DC based on the voltage. The bottom one says it is specifically DC based on the symbol. http://www.accesscomms.com.au/reference/polarity.htm

Comment: They will still mark the tip as + even on AC. Only a AC/DC volt meter will show for sure.